# I'm trying to get WiFi working on Ubuntu server 18.04.2

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

Here is my wireless info script.

```
Intel® 802.11ac WiFi Module

########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 29 Jun 2019 02:05 UTC +0000

Booted last: 29 Jun 2019 00:00 UTC +0000

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-54-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 10:55:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, maybe-ubiquity

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /home/ryan/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

24:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

25:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1849:1539]
    Kernel driver in use: igb

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

'pccardctl' is not installed (package "pcmciautils").

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                364544  0
mac80211              778240  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               286720  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              622592  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    24576  1 wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp37s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp37s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.104/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp37s0
       valid_lft 86116sec preferred_lft 86116sec
    inet6 2600:8800:5a80:237e:<IP6 'enp37s0' [IF1]>/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 60506sec preferred_lft 60506sec
    inet6 fe80::<IP6 'enp37s0' [IF1]>/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp36s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp36s0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp37s0   no wireless extensions.

wlp36s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp37s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.104 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp37s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.104 
192.168.1.1 dev enp37s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.104 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    None found.

Running:

    None found.

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager is not installed (package "network-manager").

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: No such file or directory

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

No NetworkManager profiles found.

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml]
network:
    ethernets:
        enp37s0:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Etc/UTC (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

phy#0 (self-managed)
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2437 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (2422 - 2462 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (2447 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (5170 - 5190 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5190 - 5210 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5210 - 5230 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5230 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5270 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5270 - 5290 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5290 - 5310 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5310 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5510 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5510 - 5530 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5530 - 5550 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5550 - 5570 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5570 - 5590 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5590 - 5610 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5610 - 5630 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5630 - 5650 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5650 - 5670 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5670 - 5690 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5690 - 5710 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5710 - 5730 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5755 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5755 - 5775 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5775 - 5795 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5795 - 5815 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5815 - 5835 @ 20), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp37s0   no frequency information.

wlp36s0   32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp37s0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.805 GHz

wlp36s0   Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'DSM' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-29 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"DSM"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000038527f14b5
                    Extra: Last beacon: 872ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'DSM_5GHz' [AC2]>
                    Channel:36
                    Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
                    Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"DSM_5GHz"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000003852931ac2
                    Extra: Last beacon: 360ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'DSM_5GHz' [AC3]>
                    Channel:161
                    Frequency:5.805 GHz
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"DSM_5GHz"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000003852777f6b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 116ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'DSM' [AC4]>
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=41/70  Signal level=-69 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"DSM"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000858b6cf788c
                    Extra: Last beacon: 788ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-54-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     FB4FB080CDB2B0BB4EF37DB
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlmvm
vermagic:       4.15.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-54-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     10B87D6D65DDD085D1326C9
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-54-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-a0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-hr-a0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-f0-hr-a0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0-34.ucode
srcversion:     1AD55A6BECD5B5DFB5BBF7E
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       4.15.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-54-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     C615A4309BFED95CEE6CECF
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
d0i3_timeout: 1000
disable_11ac: N
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mdadm.conf]
options md_mod start_ro=1

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-snap.network-manager.rules]
# network-manager
KERNEL=="rfkill", TAG+="snap_network-manager_networkmanager"
# ppp
KERNEL=="ppp", TAG+="snap_network-manager_networkmanager"
# ppp
KERNEL=="tty[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*", TAG+="snap_network-manager_networkmanager"
TAG=="snap_network-manager_networkmanager", RUN+="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper $env{ACTION} snap_network-manager_networkmanager $devpath $major:$minor"

##### dmesg #############################

[   13.960341] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   14.035659] iwlwifi 0000:24:00.0 wlp36s0: renamed from wlan0
[   18.685109] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp37s0: link is not ready
[   21.729855] igb 0000:25:00.0 enp37s0: igb: enp37s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[   21.945530] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp37s0: link becomes ready
[ 2247.075760] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp36s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[ 2247.147595] NetworkManager[22981]: segfault at 8 ip 000000000048ad06 sp 00007ffe6f47d540 error 4 in NetworkManager[400000+2b7000]
[ 2247.739289] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp36s0: link is not ready
[ 2247.758050] NetworkManager[23245]: segfault at 8 ip 000000000048ad06 sp 00007ffde6970b90 error 4 in NetworkManager[400000+2b7000]
[ 2248.238236] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp36s0: link is not ready (repeated 3 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please edit your question and format pasted output as `code` by using the { } icon.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What I am trying to do is get my wifi working on the computer that the server is running on.  The server is running on ASRock motherboard and is the only thing running on the computer.